# Suppose we toss a coin 5 times and define Y as number of runs of heads. How do you find expectation and variance?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Range would be {0,1,2,3,4,5}

Is there an easy way to find expectation rather than writing out all the possible outcomes?

Comment: If you get 5 heads, does that count as 5 "runs of heads" or just 1? I.e. are you just counting heads or are you counting how many contiguous runs of heads there are separated by tails?

Comment: Yeah that would count as a run. HHHTH would be 2 runs. Sorry forgot to put that in the description

Answer (score 1):

You can only get at most 3 runs, so one way to go is to simply compute the probability of getting $n$ runs for $n=0,1,2,3$. The probability of getting $0$ runs is easy to compute for any number of coins, and also there is only one way to get 3 runs with 5 coins so that probability is also easy to compute. Let $P_k(n)$ be the probability of getting $n$ runs with $k$ coins where the last coin was a head, and $Q_k(n)$ be the probability of getting $n$ runs with $k$ coins where the last coin was a tail. Then $Q_k(n) = 1/2(P_{k-1}(n) + Q_{k-1}(n))$, and $P_k(n) = 1/2(P_{k-1}(n) + Q_{k-1}(n-1))$. You can use these formulas to get the probability of getting $1$ or $2$ runs with 5 coins, by building up from.1 coin. (Noting that the total probability of getting $n$ runs is $P_k(n) + Q_k(n)$) Once you know the probabilities for the outcomes, the formulas for expectation and variance are trivial.

Comment: +1 for providing a workable scheme, but I strongly suspect the math of the recurrence works out a bit more clearly if you work with enumerating outcomes and divide by $2^k$ if you need probabilities.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Sure, that would just remove the $1/2$ factor in front of the recurrences but it would be a little bit neater, agreed.